fabricjs: how to use loadSVGFromURL with react useEffect?
I tried to render a SVG onto my canvas using useEffect, like this:
// store canvas reference
const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState<fabric.Canvas>();
    useEffect(() => {
        const c = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
          height: 700,
          width: 700,
          backgroundColor: "white",
        });
        setCanvas(c);
        c.renderAll();
        return () => {
          c.dispose();
        };
      }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/example.svg', (objects, options) => {
        const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        // Add the SVG to the canvas and render
        canvas?.add(svg);
        canvas?.renderAll();
      })
    // wait for canvas to mount first
    }, [canvas]);

However there is nothing being rendered on the canvas, I found no similar projects online and don't know the correct practice in loading SVG with react. What am I doing wrong?

Well, your code looks good but if you can't load svg with Fabric.js, you can confirm several things.

you need to check svg file path is corrct or not.
you need to check Fabric.js package version.

I made a simple react project to show you how to load svg with Fabric.js. I provide the sample code.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const FabricPanel = () => {
    // States for Canvas
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvasRef.current) {
            const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
                fireMiddleClick: true,
                stopContextMenu: true, 
                selection: true,
                preserveObjectStacking: true
            });
    
            setCanvas(fabricCanvas);
    
            fabricCanvas.backgroundColor = '#131313';
            fabricCanvas.renderAll();

            return () => {
                fabricCanvas.dispose();
            };
        }
    }, []);

    // Load and center SVG on the canvas
    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvas) {
            fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/images/bnb.svg', (objects, options) => {
                const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                // Add the SVG to the canvas and render
                canvas?.add(svg);
                canvas?.renderAll();
            });
        }
    }, [canvas]);

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="800" height="600" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default FabricPanel;



You can find this project here: Github, Stackblitz

Thank you! I revert fabric back to 5.3.0 and my code works (previously 6.4.0). Do you have any idea why it doesn't work in the new package version? I also had to use different promise handling for even loading an image from URL.

Well, it seems like Fabic 6.4.0 is not stable version.
